# Count from one table and matching count from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a work order table and customer satisfaction table.
i need to count distinct location from work order and i need to count matching location from customersatisfaction. the common column is wo_number

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, WO.wo_completionDate), 0), 111) AS [Period Date],
REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, WO.wo_completionDate), 0), 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS Period,
count (distinct WO.fu_unitID),
count (distinct SR.fu_unitID)
from v_surveyResultRpt as SR
INNER JOIN v_workorder AS WO on SR.wo_number = WO.wo_number
where WO.wo_isClosed = '1' and WO.wo_charge = '1' and WO.rc_code = 'CD-HM'
and
DATEDIFF(MONTH,WO.wo_completionDate,getdate()) < 6
group by DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, WO.wo_completionDate), 0)
order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, WO.wo_completionDate), 0), 111)
```

Expecting a result like
Month-YY, Total_location from customer satisfaction survey, total location from work order.
Ultimately it will give me the how many customer responded from the total work order.

Comment: . . I removed the mysql tag because the syntax is obviously SQL Server.  You should include sample data and desired results.  A db fiddle of some sort would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below sample code, if it helps to you.

```
select CAST(MONTH(WO.wo_completionDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) +'-'+ CAST(YEAR(WO.wo_completionDate) AS VARCHAR(4)),
count (distinct WO.fu_unitID),
count (distinct SR.fu_unitID)
from v_surveyResultRpt as SR
INNER JOIN v_workorder AS WO on SR.wo_number = WO.wo_number
where WO.wo_isClosed = '1' and WO.wo_charge = '1' and WO.rc_code = 'CD-HM'
and DATEDIFF(MONTH,WO.wo_completionDate,getdate()) < 6
group by MONTH(WO.wo_completionDate), YEAR(WO.wo_completionDate)
order by YEAR(WO.wo_completionDate), MONTH(WO.wo_completionDate)
```

Comment: its not working showing "Invalid column name 'fu_unitID'."

Comment: Check that columns in v_workorder. i think it doesn't relate to this logic.